# cannot install ggplot 2 with R 4.0.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the title suggest I can install ggplot2 with R 4.0.1 while I was able with R 3.6.2.
There is no question about what cause the error : R and utf-8 ...

```
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
Error in lazyLoadDBinsertVariable(vars[i], from, datafile, ascii, compress,  : 
  impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'C:/Users/prÃ©nom/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/00LOCK-ggplot2/00new/ggplot2/data/Rdata.rdb' : No such file or directory
ERROR: lazydata failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/prénom/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
```

The error is clear as you can see R download the file in the right place and try to install in the wrong place ...

Then my question is : How do I fix that ?

I don't know how to install ggplot2 manually or even if it's possibleI used Rgui (i'm on windows) as I first think that it was Rstudio fault but no ...

It worked perfectly with R3.6.2 ...

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the utf problem, but you can always change the target directory *indirectly* by changing `.libPaths()`. That is, create a temp-dir somewhere that does not have accented letters (or spaces?) in the dir-path, prepend it to your list of install locations (`.libPaths("/new/path", .libPaths())`), and try installing again. Once installed, you can move the `ggplot2` directory (and perhaps any other dependencies installed during this process) manually.

Comment: it work perfectly can you please make an Answer then I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to install into a temporary path (without utf problems) and move it over. For instance,

```r
temppath <- "c:/temp/R123"
.libPaths(temppath, .libPaths())
install.packages("dplyr")
```

When that's done, move `ggplot2` (and any other package directories installed by dependency within `temppath`) into your "normal" library path (with the utf issue).

If you don't do any cleanup, then *in the current R session*, any follow-on `install.packages` will still install into `temppath`, which is fine ... just move them over (e.g., Windows Explorer, git-bash, etc). You can prevent this from happening with `.libPaths(.libPaths()[-1])` (which will remove the first element). This is a hasty no-checks kind of command, though, don't run it multiple times or you'll run out of lib-paths.

Or you can just restart R. Since we didn't save this `temppath` method into `.Rprofile` or `.Renviron`, a fresh R will work as if it was never done.

Answer (score 0):

try `install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)`